# Database transactions - or is this a normalization issue?

Tags: sql, database, transactions, normalization

Lets say a student enrolled in a particular course. His total fee is $25000 (base on other computations such as tuition fee, miscellaneous fees, etc.).

Now, this is what confuses me.
How can I *get* AND *compute* the total remaining balance of the student. Should I:

1. Subtract the amount he paid from his total balance(a column in my table) every time he pays.
2. Do not **ever** modify any column, but use another attribute called total_fee column. Just get the total amount he paid from every transactions that can be found in my tution_payment table, and then subtract the result from the total_fee(this can be done through my query). Also please be noted that I didnt use total_balance here.

I remember someone told me that

> *Financial transactions are generally only inserted*

Does this mean that my former solution is right? Currently, I use the latter, but feels that it is an inaccurate solution.

I  am not familiar with how databases represent accounting transactions, so  any help will be  much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, there would be a table with transactions.  The student fee would be booked as credit to the university and debit to the student.  A repayment would be booked as credit to the student.  An interest fee would be credit to the university.

That way, there is no need to store a balance.  You calculate the balance based on the transaction history.  The biggest advantage is that you can explain the balance; it's not just a number stored in a database, but it has a full history of how it came to be.

Comment: Definitely go with a double entry accounting model. (+1)  Any other approach will eventually land you in trouble, being unable to explain or justify your numbers.

Comment: @Andomar - You mean I didnt have to record the balance in a column? That all I need is a table for transactions that I can sum up(through a view/query), and possibly other computations, to get the total balance?